# Parse boolean expression python

Tags: string, parsing, comparison, boolean-logic, separator

I have a boolean expression as a string like: `"Hello, world/earth , how"` and so on where `/` is `OR` and `,` is `AND`

I want to compare a string with this boolean expression and return `True` if the string contains `"Hello" AND ("world" OR "earth") AND "how"`

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a graph [(python-graph)](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/) if you now something about finite automata, where every word is a node and every node points to the next possible words. In your example "Hello" would point to "world" and "earth", these would point to "how". It should be easy to go through your graph then.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could but it seems a bit overkill to install a library for this "simple" task. Since the words can be in any order and there might be other words I can't really traverse forward and get into a final state?

Comment: ok I assumed the order was important. You could split the expresson by comma, then you get a list ["hello", "world/earth", "how"]. Iterate through that list, if the word doesn't contain "/" it has to be in it, if it does contain "/" split by that and one of them has to be in the string.